# How to stop method fith toggle button?

Tags: java, android

I have some problem with simply code. Maybe some of you can see what I can not. I can not believe that I'm gonna post this question but two days for soloving this is to much. I wanna stop executing method on toogle button click. This is my code. Method that I wanna stop is getData().

```
      toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                                    if (isChecked) {
                                                        toggleButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(toggleFree));
                                                        isItAviable = true;
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(isItAviable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    } else {
                                                        isItAviable = false;
                                                        toggleButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(toggleBusy));
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(isItAviable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                    }

                                                    if (isItAviable) {
                                                        getData();  //thi is method that I want to stop on click.
                                                    }

                                                }


                                            }
    );``
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "stop methods".

You CAN:
1) Break out of loops.
2) Kill threads.

What does the method getData() contain?

Comment: `You don't "stop methods"` you can use `return` ?

Comment: That method getting some values from Firebase, and I want to stop thet on one click and on next click to make it alive again...and don't know kow to do that...

Comment: We seem to be getting somewhere. 
Are you using a listener on a Firebase table/collection/reference?
If so, you could pass a boolean true/false in to the method that either adds or removes the Listener.

Answer (score 0):

If that method is not accessing UI elements, you can first run it on a different thread, and then when the toggle click you can kill the thread.

find more on:

Using threads:
[Specify the code to run on a thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable)

Interrupting threads in JAVA:
[How to Kill a Java Thread](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop)